# Longest Palindromic Subsequence For Loops

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am practicing some Dynamic Programming problems and I came across this problem - 
http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/longest-palindromic-subsequence/.

I am not understanding two lines from the below code (from the link) - 
(I have marked them 1 and 2)

```
 for(int sublen = 2;sublen<=chars.length;sublen++){ 
                for(int i=0;i<=LP.length-sublen;i++){ //--> 1
                    int j = i+sublen-1; // --> 2 
                    if(chars[i]==chars[j] && sublen==2){
                        LP[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    else if(chars[i]==chars[j]){
                        LP[i][j] = LP[i+1][j-1]+2;
                    }
                    else{
                        LP[i][j] = Math.max(LP[i+1][j],LP[i][j-1]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone please help me understand why are we using the 2nd and 3rd line from the above code ? 
In line 2 , why is he doing `LP.length-sublen` ?